# Ubuntu bluetooth mouse not connecting

Tags: ubuntu, bluetooth, mouse

Ubuntu 19.10
It was working until recently. Although, I did have press the button on the bottom of the mouse frequently.

Here's the output of: tail -f /var/log/syslog | grep bluetooth

while I tried a bunch of things.

> drew@drew-ThinkPad-T520:/var/log$ tail -f syslog | grep bluetooth Jan
>   14 10:45:28 drew-ThinkPad-T520 bluetoothd[1057]: Endpoint registered:
>   sender=:1.202 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSink/sbc Jan 14 10:45:28
>   drew-ThinkPad-T520 bluetoothd[1057]: Endpoint registered:
>   sender=:1.202 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource/sbc Jan 14 10:45:55
>   drew-ThinkPad-T520 bluetoothd[1057]: 0C:FC:CA:00:08:5D: error updating
>   services: Operation already in progress (114) Jan 14 10:46:53
>   drew-ThinkPad-T520 bluetoothd[1057]: Refusing input device connect: No
>   such file or directory (2) Jan 14 10:46:53 drew-ThinkPad-T520
>   bluetoothd[1057]: Refusing connection from 0C:FC:CA:00:08:5D: unknown
>   device Jan 14 10:46:57 drew-ThinkPad-T520 bluetoothd[1057]: Refusing
>   input device connect: No such file or directory (2) Jan 14 10:46:57
>   drew-ThinkPad-T520 bluetoothd[1057]: Refusing connection from
>   0C:FC:CA:00:08:5D: unknown device Jan 14 10:47:48 drew-ThinkPad-T520
>   bluetoothd[1057]: Endpoint unregistered: sender=:1.202
>   path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSink/sbc Jan 14 10:47:48 drew-ThinkPad-T520
>   bluetoothd[1057]: Endpoint unregistered: sender=:1.202
>   path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource/sbc Jan 14 10:48:15 drew-ThinkPad-T520
>   bluetoothd[1057]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.202
>   path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSink/sbc Jan 14 10:48:15 drew-ThinkPad-T520
>   bluetoothd[1057]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.202
>   path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource/sbc Jan 14 10:48:33 drew-ThinkPad-T520
>   bluetoothd[1057]: Refusing input device connect: No such file or
>   directory (2) Jan 14 10:48:33 drew-ThinkPad-T520 bluetoothd[1057]:
>   Refusing connection from 0C:FC:CA:00:08:5D: unknown device Jan 14
>   10:48:37 drew-ThinkPad-T520 bluetoothd[1057]: Refusing input device
>   connect: No such file or directory (2) Jan 14 10:48:37
>   drew-ThinkPad-T520 bluetoothd[1057]: Refusing connection from
>   0C:FC:CA:00:08:5D: unknown device Jan 14 10:48:43 drew-ThinkPad-T520
>   bluetoothd[1057]: Refusing input device connect: No such file or
>   directory (2) Jan 14 10:48:43 drew-ThinkPad-T520 bluetoothd[1057]:
>   Refusing connection from 0C:FC:CA:00:08:5D: unknown device Jan 14
>   10:48:46 drew-ThinkPad-T520 bluetoothd[1057]: Refusing input device
>   connect: No such file or directory (2) Jan 14 10:48:46
>   drew-ThinkPad-T520 bluetoothd[1057]: Refusing connection from
>   0C:FC:CA:00:08:5D: unknown device Jan 14 10:49:21 drew-ThinkPad-T520
>   bluetoothd[1057]: Refusing input device connect: No such file or
>   directory (2) Jan 14 10:49:21 drew-ThinkPad-T520 bluetoothd[1057]:
>   Refusing connection from 0C:FC:CA:00:08:5D: unknown device Jan 14
>   10:49:27 drew-ThinkPad-T520 bluetoothd[1057]: 0C:FC:CA:00:08:5D: error
>   updating services: Host is down (112) Jan 14 10:50:41
>   drew-ThinkPad-T520 bluetoothd[1057]: Refusing input device connect: No
>   such file or directory (2) Jan 14 10:50:41 drew-ThinkPad-T520
>   bluetoothd[1057]: Refusing connection from 0C:FC:CA:00:08:5D: unknown
>   device Jan 14 10:50:42 drew-ThinkPad-T520 bluetoothd[1057]: Refusing
>   input device connect: No such file or directory (2) Jan 14 10:50:42
>   drew-ThinkPad-T520 bluetoothd[1057]: Refusing connection from
>   0C:FC:CA:00:08:5D: unknown device

OC:FC:CA:00:08:5D is the address reported in the Bluetooth settings window that pops up when I try to connect. The status briefly changes to Connected then returns to Disconnected after about a second.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$ dmesg | grep -i bluetooth | grep -i firmware
```

I've get a firmware error:

```
[   16.230350] bluetooth hci0: Direct firmware load for brcm/BCM-0a5c-6412.hcd failed with error -2
```

I had find the driver on git:

[Broadcom firmware](https://github.com/winterheart/broadcom-bt-firmware)

And copy and rename in driver's directory:

```
$ sudo cp /share/BCM4350C5-0a5c-6412.hcd /lib/firmware/brcm/BCM-0a5c-6412.hcd
```